# Set Alarms in android Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

I am a beginner in android and was working on a small project where multiple user sign up and perform different action like posting, liking, commenting. All data being stored on fire-base database and storage. I want to build an 'Events module' in the app, that helps each user set their own event, descriptions, time and days to give them reminders. I am unable to work as I don't know where to start. What should I use. I tried searching alarm manager but I really am not getting it so much. Many people have worked using SQLlite and alarm manager but I don't want to use sqlLite. Help me what should I start.

Comment: It depends on alarm. If only the person who wants to get notified then you should go with sqlite

Comment: Thankyou for replying @Ashish. Yes, only the person who set the event should get notified but what I wanted was all my data to use a single database. Because what I think, it will help me getting the id's of the users more easily as compared to using another database tool.

Comment: @Farezeen Saleem you can store them in firebase but when you want to send only single user notification just store data in your sqlite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to this a day after. The reason why we need to choose sqlite and not firebase is because alarms are locally stored on our mobile devices. Sqlite helps in such process whereas firebase works as cloud which is usually not recommended and used for alarms or calendars!!! Cheers